# checkbox problems with javascript & php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to make a simple button disappear if the checkboxes are not checked with JavaScript. My HTML is inside my PHP. Now the button disappears if the website is not loaded as there are no checkboxes checked (hard coded). But if I were to check a checkbox, the button appears. After I uncheck the checkbox, it is still visible. Please help me, I tried everything for the last 2 days on this problem.

my php:

```
echo  "<form action='printdata.php' method='post'>";

echo  "<tr> <td><input type='checkbox' onclick='hide()' name='id[]' value='". $row['id']."'></td>";
echo  "<td class='data'>". $row["host"]    . "</td>";
echo  "<td class='data'>". $row["ether"]   . "</td>";
echo  "<td class='data'>". $row["ip"]      . "</td>";
echo  "<td class='data'>". $row["gateway"] . "</td>";
echo  "<td class='data'>". $row["netmask"] . "</td>";
echo  "<td class='data'>". $row["dns"]     . "</td>";
echo  "<td class='data'>". $row["netwerk"] . "</td>";

echo "<td class='data'><a href=\"/sending/delete.php?id=".$row['id']."\"><i class='fa fa-fw fa-send'></i></a>
      <td class='data'><a href=\"/sending/edit.php?id=".$row['id']."\"><i class='fa fa-fw fa-pencil'></i></a><BR></td>
      <td class='data'><a href=\"/sending/print.php?print=".$row['id']."\"><i class='fa fa-fw fa-print'></i></a></td>
      <td class='data'><a href=\"/sending/duplicate.php?id=".$row['id']."\"><i class='fa fa-fw fa-copy'></i></a></td>
      </td>"; 

}
echo  "</table>";                
echo  "<div id='hidebutton'>"; 
echo  "<button type='submit' name='submit' value='print'><td class='data'><i class='fa fa-fw fa-copy'></i></a>print</button></td></form>";
echo  "</div></div>";
```

My javascript:

```
window.onload = function now() {
  var button = document.getElementById("hidebutton");
  button.style.display = "none";
}

function checknow(){ 
  var button = document.getElementById("hidebutton");
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('[id="' + hidecheckbox + '"]');
  var test = checkboxes.checked = true;
           
  if(test){ 
      console.log("show");

      button.style.display = "block";
  }else{ 
      console.log("hide");
        button.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: I’m puzzled by your use of querySelectorAll. That one is meant to find several elements, but you are searching for an ID, which is unique! Do you want to check *all* row checkboxes of the table, or only one? What’s the value of hidecheckbox?

Comment: Where is your closing TR tag? Also ` echo "<td class='data'><a href=....` is missing closing TD tag and final TD has two closing TD tags...

Answer (score 0):

[`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) is returning a NodeList, which has no property like `checked`. It does not work like jQuery (:

You‘d need to check each one yourself. Replace your `test =` with:

```js
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('tr input[type="checkbox"]');
const allChecked = !Array.from(checkboxes).some(cb => cb.checked !== true))
```

[The `Array.some()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) will stop iterating on the array as soon as it finds one element that fulfils the condition.

### Some other improvements

Avoid redundancy in PHP by eliminating `echo` in each line, and by using short echo tags for variables. This will improve readability of your code:

```php
// end php code
?>
<td class="data"><a href="/sending/delete.php?id=<?= $row['id'] ?>"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-send"></i></a></td>
<? // continue php code
```

If you wanted to select an element by means of an ID, using an attribute selector is possible, but way to complicated. Use one of the following:

```js
document.getElementById(hidecheckbox);
// OR
document.querySelector('#' + hidecheckbox);
```

See [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Inputs, including checkboxes, need labels. Suggestion:

```html
<tr><th scope="row"><input type="checkbox" aria-label="Select row <?= $row['id'] ?>"…
```

Also links absolutely need a unique text explaining where they lead to. This is very important to assistive technology, which users with disabilities rely on.

```html
<td class="data"><a href="/sending/delete.php?id=<?= $row['id'] ?>/"><i aria-label="Delete" class="fa fa-fw fa-send"></i></a>
```

Finally, do not hide the button, but make it disabled. That way users know what they will be able to do once they checked all checkboxes.

```js
button.disabled = !allChecked;
```

If you did want to hide the button, use the [`hidden` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden), it’s way shorter:

```js
button.hidden = !allChecked;
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply! you really helped me out. Wish u the best!